# How to connect node.js to mysql on google compute engine?

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-compute-engine

I am running an instance on Google Compute Engine. I installed mysql and node.js on this instance.

I have put the following in the index.js file:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var mysql_connection = mysql.createConnection(
{
    host: "instance external IP",
    user: "my_user_name",
    password: "my_pw",
    database: "my_db"
}
);

mysql_connection.connect(err => 
    {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to the database.");
    });
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
```

How do I connect node.js to mysql on compute engine?
Do I need to get a different host address instead of the external IP, if so, what is it or where do I find it? 
Is the require("mysql") the issue, if so, how do I fix this to find the mysql module on the compute engine instance?

Comment: Have you installed the mysql module (e.g. "npm install mysql") ?

Comment: You might also consider connecting to localhost or a unix socket rather than the external IP, but this is not your immediate issue.

Comment: @robsiemb yes, I did npm install mysql on the compute engine instance. I made a db and tables on it also.

Comment: can you see the node_modules folder in root directory? And lots of folders there as mysql npm got dependencies?

Comment: I'm confused -- npm would install just the client library modules, which node will need, and clearly isn't being found by the error you are getting.  You likely used apt or a similar package manager to install the mysql server (which would allow you to create a database and tables).

Comment: @robsiemb  you were right, i must have used apt and forgot because after Asif mentioned checking the node_modules, i looked and didnt see any mysql folders so I ran npm install mysql and they are all there now and the node.js script is not throwing an error now. Well, thank you both for the assist - saved me a lot of headaches trying to figure out what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments conversation above, install the mysql node module using:

```
npm install mysql
```